# Can JMeter replay a test in a browser?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, katalon-studio

Is it possible to get JMeter to replay its recordings via a browser, so one can see the replay in action. Katalon can do this, but not sure about JMeter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As per [JMeter project main page](http://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, **it works at protocol level**. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So JMeter doesn't actually kick off a real browser, it only sends [HTTP Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) like real browsers, but it doesn't render response, just measures time from sending request to receiving the last byte of the response. Therefore as of current version [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5) it is not possible

The only way you can visualize the test results and see the request and response details is using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener. By default in `Text` mode you can see the source HTML code of the page JMeter hits

[image]

However in `HTML`, `HTML (download resources)` and `Browser` modes you should be able to see the rendered response:

[image]